# Finding the occurrences in list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the max occurrences for each index in the list. For example, if the occurences in Index 0 have 5 times "find" then 5 is recorded and if Index 1 has 2 times "find" then 2 is recorded. So for Both Index 0 and Index 1 will get 5 , 2.

```
a = [{'test': []}, 
     {'test': [{'testing': 'Not', 'Nottesting': 'Yes'}]},
     {'test': [{'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'yes'}]},
     {'test': [{'testing': 'maybe', 'Nottesting': 'yes'},
               {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'maybe'},
               {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'haha'},
               {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'sometimes'},
               {'testing': 'sowell', 'Nottesting': 'some'}]},
     {},
     {}]
```

## Is there a way to print the count based on the max of each list?

```
aa = []
for index, l in enumerate(a):
    count = 0
    find = []
    for trying in l.get("test", []):
        if trying["testing"] == "find":
            count += 1
            print(count)
```

I tried to use the method suggested but to no avail.

My current output:

```
1
1
2
3
```

Expected output

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just indent the printing directive backwards so that it would only be executed after the nested loop, not on every occurence.

```
for index, l in enumerate(a):
    count = 0
    find = []

    for trying in l.get("test", []):
        if trying["testing"] == "find":
            count += 1

    if count : print(count)
```

Comment: I tried but I get the following output: 0 0 1 3 0 0

Comment: I tried many different indent and dont know why all will include the zeroes as well

Comment: @Beginner Because `count` is initialized with the value `0`, it will always print this value... Have a look at my small change.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing inside loop where you are increasing count. You need to print it outside.

```
a = [{'test': []}, {'test': [{'testing': 'Not', 'Nottesting': 'Yes'}]}, {'test': [{'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'yes'}]}, {'test': [{'testing': 'maybe', 'Nottesting': 'yes'}, {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'maybe'}, {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting':'haha'}, {'testing': 'find', 'Nottesting': 'sometimes'}, {'testing': 'sowell', 'Nottesting': 'some'}]}, {}, {}]

aa = []
for index, l in enumerate(a):
    count = 0
    find = []
    for trying in l.get("test", []):
        if trying["testing"] == "find":
            count += 1
    if count != 0:
        print(count)
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you sir, could you tell me why are there zeroes ? I still dont get why

Comment: count of find is 0 for some index in a and hence there are 0's

Answer (score 2):

Or one-liner:

```
print([sum([1 for x in i.get('test',[]) if x['testing']=='find']) for i in a if sum([1 for x in i.get('test',[]) if x['testing']=='find'])!=0])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Or two-liner (more readable):

```
l=[sum([1 for x in i.get('test',[]) if x['testing']=='find']) for i in a]
print(list(filter(None,l)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: One-liners are the best liners.

Comment: @SvenKrüger Correct, shortest, and best, note that `for` loops are slow, and list comprehensions aren't

Comment: @Tryph Yeah tho, :-), lol, i live on unreadable stuff hahaha, :-)

Comment: @Tryph Now :-) ?